# Why are h1 and button misaligned

Tags: html, css

I've noticed something quite strange, I can't seem to get h1 and button html elements aligned.
I've removed borders and paddings however there still seems to be a consistent misalignment. I am unsure what is happening, can someone please explain why this behavior is occurring? I have attached a picture of the end result:

[image]

```
<head>
    <style>
        button {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            display:inline-block;
            height:30px;
            width:100px;
            background:lightblue;
            vertical-align: text-top;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size:20px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        h1 {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            display:inline-block;
            height:30px;
            width:100px;
            background:lightblue;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size:20px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        div {
            background:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Head</h1>
        <button>Head</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Add display: flex to the div

Comment: You should use classes to organize your content, especially where it gets repetitive.. 
add align-items: center; display: inline-flex; to the container div and remove display from others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `verticle-align: top;` instead of `verticle-align: text-top;` because `verticle-align: text-top;` effect only text. And there is a default `border-width: 2px;` to button so remove if you don't need.

```css
button {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            display:inline-block;
            height:30px;
            width:100px;
            background:lightblue;
            vertical-align: top;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size:20px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        h1 {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            display:inline-block;
            height:30px;
            width:100px;
            background:lightblue;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size:20px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        div {
            background:red;
        }
```

```html
<div>
        <h1>Head</h1>
        <button>Head</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you wanna h1 tag and button together then here is your solve....**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        button {
            margin-top:-4px;
            margin-left: -4px;
            padding:0px;
            display:inline-block;
            height:30px;
            width:100px;
            background:lightblue;
            vertical-align: text-top;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size:20px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        h1 {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            display:inline-block;
            height:30px;
            width:100px;
            background:lightblue;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size:20px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        div {
            background:red;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
        <div>
            <h1>Head</h1>
            <button>Head</button>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will be fine

        button {

```
             margin-top: 1px;
            padding: 0px;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 30px;
            width: 100px;
            background: lightblue;
            vertical-align: top;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
    }

    h1 {
            margin: 0px;
            margin-top: 2px;
            margin-left: 4px;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
            padding-top: 3px;
            padding-left: 23px;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 24px;
            width: 70px;
            background: lightblue;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;  
    }

    div {
        background:red;
    }
</style>
```